# SoapUI project teardown script not executed when run via commandline

Tags: soapui

I have a SoapUI project with a project TearDown Script.

When I run all test suites via the UI, the TearDown script is properly executed.

Via the commandline "testrunner myProject.xml" the TearDown script is not run.

Comment: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/do-tear-down-scripts-work-when-testrunner-is-run-on-the-command/td-p/111065  check out this and https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Setup-and-teardown-scripts-are-not-executed-from-commandline/td-p/36206  this may answer your question.. Use some logging commands

Comment: Had found both threads already, both are about tear down scripts on test case level, my issue is about tear down scripts on project level. Also, in both threads no solution is given. Logging in tear down scripts is also only shown when run from the GUI, but not from the command line.